# IOS rss feed login

Tags: iphone, ios, xml, xcode, wordpress

im developing an app that retrieves a rss feed from a website but i need to have the website in private, so how do i authenticate my app to get the rss content of the website.

Im working with wordpress btw.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [feedburner](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/feedburner-plugin/) plugin, and follow the instruction given in plugin site.

Hope this helps you... :-)

Answer (score 1):

use the WordPress feed burner plugin..
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/feedburner-plugin/